# Set default notNullable reference column in Knex migration only for existing rows

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, database-migration, knex.js

I have a postgresql database, and I am trying the following migration to add a non-nullable reference column to an existing table, using Knex:

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.table('Donation', (table) => {
    table.integer('causeId').notNullable();
    table.foreign('causeId').references('Cause.id');
  });
};
```

When I run this migration, I get the following error due to existing rows:

```
error: alter table "Donation" add column "causeId" integer not null - column "causeId" contains null values
```

I want to seed the column with a default value **only** for existing rows. For subsequent insertions, I would rather the insert fail if a value is not provided, so `.notNullable().defaultTo(...)` won't work.

I was thinking of maybe using `defaultTo()` only for the initial migration and then removing the constraint after, but I'm drawing a blank on how to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution ended up being to use `defaultTo(...)` on creation of this column and then alter it afterwards using `alterTable(...)`.

Not sure of a better way, but this works.

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  function relateCauseToDonation() {
    return knex.schema.table('Donation', (table) => {
      table.integer('causeId').notNullable().defaultTo(1);
      table.foreign('causeId').references('Cause.id');
    });
  }

  function removeDefaultToFromCauseId() {
    return knex.schema.alterTable('Donation', (table) => {
      table.integer('causeId').notNullable().alter();
    });
  }

  return relateCauseToDonation().then(removeDefaultToFromCauseId);
};
```

Comment: Your solution is the standard one database developers have used for years. But now go back and remove your default if you still want subsequent insert to fail (if you haven't already). Also go ahead and Accept your answer so the question doesn't appear unresolved.

Comment: @Belayer Appreciate the response. Stack overflow won't let me accept my own answer for 2 days.

Comment: Limitations, ugh!  Guess I've never tried to do that.

Comment: I was looking for the same and it worked wonders, thanks for sharing

Comment: When I am inserting value and leaving the default value, I am still getting error to fill the default value too. should I share more details?